# How do I make an SQL procedure that will take entries of a column as input one by one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the table I've created and some initial values.

```
/*Make the table*/

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE(
ID int PRIMARY KEY,
NAME varchar(100) NOT NULL,
SUPERIOR_NAME varchar(100)
);

/*Give it some initial values*/

INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES(1, 'A',NULL), (2, 'B', 'E'), (3, 'C', 'A'), 
(4, 'D', 'A'), (5, 'E',NULL), (6, 'F', 'D');
```

I need to write an SQL procedure that will return all the subordinates of a person, including all sub-subordinates and so on. In this example, if I input A, I should get C, D and F (subordinate of D who is a subordinate of A) as output. But I can only get as far as one level i.e. C and D. How do I make it work for any number of levels in the hierarchy? Am I looking at it wrong?

Here's the procedure I wrote to do it for one level:

```
USE DB
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GETSUBS @NAME VARCHAR(100)

AS
BEGIN

IF @NAME IN (SELECT SUPERIOR_NAME FROM PEOPLE)
SELECT SUPERIOR_NAME AS "NAME", NAME AS "SUBORDINATE" FROM PEOPLE WHERE
SUPERIOR_NAME=@NAME;     
END
```

I was thinking of pushing the first level results into a temporary table and using recursion, but I have no idea how the make a procedure run through entries of a column one by one. Any ideas? I use SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Comment: You may find the following article interresting : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175807(v=sql.80).aspx. And also, I strongly suggest you use the id as reference to the parent instead of the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self-referencing common-table expression and retain the top level manager (Boss) in your selection:

```
WITH OrganisationChart (Id, [Name], [Level], superior_name, [Boss]) 
AS
(
      SELECT 
            Id, [Name], 0 AS [Level], superior_name, name
      FROM
            dbo.people
      WHERE
            superior_name IS NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            emp.Id,
            emp.[Name],
            [Level] + 1,
            emp.superior_name,
            [Boss]
      FROM
            dbo.people emp
      INNER JOIN 
            OrganisationChart 
      ON
            emp.superior_name = OrganisationChart.name

)
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    OrganisationChart
WHERE 
    name != [Boss]
```

Thanks go to [Simon Ince](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2007/10/17/hello-world-and-an-introduction.aspx) for his article [Hierarchies WITH Common Table Expressions.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2007/10/17/hierarchies-with-common-table-expressions.aspx)

Comment: This was written to work with your example, but I strongly suggest to follow @Bartdude's advice to use Id's for foreign key constraints.

Comment: Thanks. This is great, except that this works only if I input a top level employee as "boss". If I have D working under A and F working under D, and input "D", I am getting a blank table instead of "F".

But never mind. I read the article, and that's due to the first select statement. I'll edit it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GETSUBS
(
    @NAME VARCHAR(100)
) -- USP_GETSUBS 'A'
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT SUPERIOR_NAME FROM PEOPLE WHERE Name=@NAME)
    BEGIN
        WITH Subordinates AS
        (
           SELECT p.ID, p.Name, p.SUPERIOR_NAME
           FROM PEOPLE AS p 
           WHERE p.Name = @NAME
           UNION ALL
           SELECT p.ID, p.Name, p.SUPERIOR_NAME
           FROM PEOPLE AS p
           INNER JOIN Subordinates AS sub ON p.SUPERIOR_NAME = sub.Name
        )

        SELECT s.SUPERIOR_NAME AS "NAME",s.Name AS "SUBORDINATE"
        FROM Subordinates AS s
        WHERE s.SUPERIOR_NAME IS NOT NULL   
    END 

END
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10981/1)**

Comment: I tried your solution, but get only C and D as subordinates of A. If indirect subordinates were included, I would see: C, D and F. I'll post an answer that does that.

Comment: check sqlfiddle demo  C, D and F are returned for input 'A'

Comment: you're right, for input 'A', F is returned as well, as subordinate of D. My comment should have been that my answer will show the ultimate boss or each employee, which makes it useful to select multiple hierarchies at once.

Answer (score 0):

You should have superior name linked on ID not on Name. That is for sure.

You can do this without recursion or CTEs by having 2 temp tables and iterating. I will pretend that you have `SuperiorID` instead of `Superior_Name`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GETSUBS 
    @ID INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @allsubs AS TABLE(ID INT)
    DECLARE @subs AS TABLE(ID INT)
    DECLARE @temp AS TABLE(ID INT)

    --Get immediate subordinates of the ID passed in
    INSERT INTO @subs(ID)
    SELECT ID FROM PEOPLE WHERE SUPERIORID = @ID

    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @subs)
    BEGIN
        DELETE @temp

        --copy the subordinate list
        INSERT INTO @temp
        SELECT (ID) FROM @subs

        DELETE @subs

        --get the subordinates' subordinates
        INSERT INTO @subs (ID)
        SELECT ID FROM PEOPLE WHERE SUPERIORID IN (
            SELECT ID FROM @temp
        )

        --add the subordinates to the full list
        INSERT INTO @allsubs (ID)
        SELECT ID FROM @temp

    END

    --select IDs from the full list
    SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT ID FROM @allsubs
    )

END
```

This will not raise an issue if too much recursion takes place - although this isn't a problem in later versions of SQLServer.

Also - [You shouldn't name stored procedures beginning 'sp_'.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)